# Can I make a string "['A', 'B', 'C']" into a list? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I made a Freckle by Renissance hack in JavaScript and I retrived the JSON base64 and decoded it using the atob() function where you get the answer but I'm just wondering if I can make the decoded string: "['A', 'B', 'C']" (The correct answers) into a list excluding the '[]' and ','.

```
async function getAnswer(){
    var id = document.getElementsByClassName("math-question__wrapper___iRtlD")[0]["dataset"]["questionId"];
    var response = await fetch("https://api.freckle.com/2/math/questions/"+id+"?lang=en", {
      method: "GET",
    
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    });

    
    json = await response.json();
    var answer=json["obfuscated-correct-answers"];
    if (typeof answer == "undefined") {
        answer=json['obfuscated-fill-in-the-blanks-correct-answers'];
    }

    
    var final=atob(answer);
    console.log(final);
}
getAnswer();
```

Comment: JSON doesn't support single-quoted strings; all strings have to be double-quoted. Are you sure that your string has single-quotes?

Comment: @ruakh it's actually base64, but that's the decoded version. Edit: without any quotes or anything

Comment: @Barmar ah, misread the question - my bad

Comment: I tried a few random IDs and it always returned "Not found". Can you give a valid ID that we can try?

Comment: How does that help? I just want an ID that I can try, like `https://api.freckle.com/2/math/questions/10?lang=en`

Comment: @Barmar https://api.freckle.com/2/math/questions/1uyts08dl7ey?lang=en should give you the answer ["150","150.00"]

Comment: That returns valid JSON, it doesn't have single quotes around the strings. Why do you think you need to deal with single quotes?

Comment: It's not a list directly. It comes out as output that way, but it's a string.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? If it returned invalid JSON you'd get an error from `response.json()`.

Comment: I'm trying to make that string into a list

Comment: Are you talking about how `console.log(final)` is printed?

Comment: Ah, I didn't decode the obfuscated strings.

Comment: The base64 decodes to a valid JSON array, too. I get `["150","150.00"]`

Comment: Exactly, I'm trying to make that into a list so I can display it properly. Also so it comes out cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base 64 string decodes to valid JSON, so use `JSON.parse()` after calling `atob()`.

```js
async function getAnswer() {
  var id = document.getElementsByClassName("math-question__wrapper___iRtlD")[0]["dataset"]["questionId"];
  var response = await fetch("https://api.freckle.com/2/math/questions/" + id + "?lang=en", {
    method: "GET",

    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
  });


  json = await response.json();
  var answer = json["obfuscated-correct-answers"];
  if (typeof answer == "undefined") {
    answer = json['obfuscated-fill-in-the-blanks-correct-answers'];
  }

  var final = JSON.parse(atob(answer));
  console.log(final);
}
getAnswer();
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this problem! Didn't know that you could do it that way!